# Return shortest string if matches in first two or more words - PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have for example, the following data in my database table...

```
30 Miles DVD
300
310 To Yuma BluRay
310 To Yuma DVD 2007
310 To Yuma DVD Wide Screen
310 To YumaYoung Guns DVD
4 Collection Fights King Of The Cage DVD
48 Hours DVD Wide Screen
49th Parallel DVD
55 Days at Peking DVD
5th Commandment DVD
6th Day BluRay
6th Day DVD 2000
6th Day The Last Action Hero Box Set DVD
7 Men From Now
7 Seconds Sell Through DVD
7 Seconds UMD Mini for PSP 2005
7 Star Grand Mantis DVD
8 Strikes Of The Wildcat DVD
800 Bullets DVD
83 Hours Til Dawn DVD
9 And A Half Ninjas DVD
```

What I want to display is the UNIQUE titles, so, most of the above are OK but where we have:

```
310 To Yuma BluRay
310 To Yuma DVD 2007
310 To Yuma DVD Wide Screen
```

I only want to show, if possible:

```
310 To Yuma BluRay
```

again from the above list where there is

```
6th Day BluRay
6th Day DVD 2000
6th Day The Last Action Hero Box Set DVD
```

I only want to show:

```
6th Day BluRay
```

Or better still "310 To Yuma" && "6th Day" respectively.

I'm thinking I need to maybe do a check on a number of letters in first word before a space then if that's over say 5 letters match with the next rows, if it does then keep adding the rows to a list somehow then when it stops matching spit out the shortest one? If the first word is less than 5 letters then move onto second word (just trying to avoid, the :: them :: this :: their etc etc)

Another way of saying it: If the first 5 characters (obv. to include spaces) match, once they stop matching get rid of what's left and print the result. Now, I also have to be careful once again with this as "The Hangover" && "The Hangover 2" are refectly plausible!

One answer suggested on an earlier version of this question was:

```
SELECT `title` FROM `PRprod_FILMS` m
  WHERE `genre` = 'Action  Adventure'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM `PRprod_FILMS` m2
        WHERE m.`title` LIKE CONCAT(m2.`title`, '%')
          AND LENGTH(m2.`title`) < LENGTH(m.`title`)
          AND m2.`genre` = m.`genre`
    )
;
```

Which kind of works but strips out some unique titles anyway so not the right answer
I wonder if this is even possible or am I asking too much or need to rethink the strategy/logic?

Darren

Comment: Ideally, you would pull out the format information into a different field and then the title field would just contain the title.

Comment: Exactly what I'm trying to do

Comment: What you're describing after "Another way of saying it" is the Longest Common Prefix problem. It's not impossible to do in MySQL but it's extremely difficult. Take a look at [this blog post on the topic](http://explainextended.com/2009/06/07/longest-common-prefix-mysql/). And there's definitely no good way to handle your "Hangover 2" issue. If you're only doing this as an intermediate step to normalize your data you should consider doing it outside of MySQL in a language more suited to the task, then dumping the results into MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 100% good solution for this that will never show duplicates or will not remove good records. However my solution would be to search for some common words (DVD, Bluray, PSP, etc) strip everything after that and make that unique. If you do this a lot, store is in another field:

```
SELECT DISTINCT( TRIM(
  LEFT(title,
    IF( LOCATE('DVD', title),
        LOCATE('DVD', title) - 1,
        IF( LOCATE('Bluray', title),
            LOCATE('Bluray', title) - 1,
            999
        )
    )
  )
)) FROM `PRprod_FILMS`
```